# How to calculate numeric age from age classes in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a dataset on animal captures for a series of year, which looks like this

```
Data<-cbind.data.frame(c("A","B","C","A","C","D","B","C","D"),
                   c("Juvenile","Adult","Adult","Adult","Adult","Juvenile","Adult","Adult","Adult"),
                   c(2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012))
colnames(Data)<-c("ID","Age_Class","Year")


 > Data
  ID Age_Class Year
1  A  Juvenile 2010
2  B     Adult 2010
3  C     Adult 2010
4  A     Adult 2011
5  C     Adult 2011
6  D  Juvenile 2011
7  B     Adult 2012
8  C     Adult 2012
9  D     Adult 2012
```

Knowing that an individual identified as "Juvenile" is 2 years old, and an individual identified as "Adult" is at least 3 years old, I would like to calculate the minimun numeric age for each individual throughout the different years. This would be the desired output:

```
> Data
  ID Age_Class Year Age_Numeric
1  A  Juvenile 2010           2
2  B     Adult 2010           3
3  C     Adult 2010           3
4  A     Adult 2011           3
5  C     Adult 2011           4
6  D  Juvenile 2011           2
7  B     Adult 2012           5
8  C     Adult 2012           5
9  D     Adult 2012           3
```

If someone can help out, or point me to a previous question on this, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `case_when`, set 2 for Juvenile, and for Adult 3 plus the difference between the given year and the first year as Adult:

```r
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Age = case_when(Age_Class == "Juvenile" ~ 2,
                         Age_Class == "Adult" ~ 3 + Year - first(Year[Age_Class == "Adult"]))) %>%
  ungroup()

  ID    Age_Class  Year   Age
1 A     Juvenile   2010     2
2 B     Adult      2010     3
3 C     Adult      2010     3
4 A     Adult      2011     3
5 C     Adult      2011     4
6 D     Juvenile   2011     2
7 B     Adult      2012     5
8 C     Adult      2012     5
9 D     Adult      2012     3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll mark the question as solved, but I have an additional question if I may. If I extend the ageing system to four classes: "1KJ" being 0 years old, "2KJ" being 1 year old, "2KJ" being atleast 3 years old, and then ">1KJ" being atleast 2 years old. The data could look something like this: `Data<-cbind.data.frame(c("A","A","A","A","A","A"),
                       c("1KJ",">1KJ",">1KJ",">2KJ",">1KJ",">2KJ"),
                       c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015))
colnames(Data)<-c("ID","Age_Class","Year")` What would be the way of dealing with this ">1KJ" class?

Comment: Depend on some conditions. It might be worth creating a new question. This might be possible to handle in the `first` command by adding multiple conditions in the equality, e.g. `Age_Class %in% c("1KJ", "2KJ")`, but unsure